# C# File Handling: Create file in directory where executable exists

Tags: c#, file-io

I am creating a standalone application that will be distributed to many users. Now each may place the executable in different places on their machines.
I wish to create a new file in the directory from where the executable was executed. So, if the user has his executable in :

```
C:\exefile\
```

The file is created there, however if the user stores the executable in:

```
C:\Users\%Username%\files\
```

the new file should be created there.

I do not wish to hard code the path in my application, but identify where the executable exists and create the file in that folder. How can I achieve this?

Comment: This is done by default with standalone application.

Comment: The user may choose to place the file in a location that requires elevation to access, or maybe place it on a read-only filesystem. That same elevation won't necessarily occur when your program runs. It would be better to place any files you're creating in the [appropriate part of the file system](http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/6/a/e6aa654f-cccb-421e-9b50-3392e9886084/VistaFileSysNamespaces.pdf).

Comment: Use `IsolatedStorage` instead...you would be able to access that even with the lowest permissions

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: True. I had forgotten to consider that. Tigran's solution incorporates what you suggest. Thanks! And thanks for that pdf too. Quite useful!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Never create a file into the directory where executable stays. Especially with the latest OSes available on the market, you can easily jump into the security issues, on file creation. 
In order to *gurantee* the file creation process, so your data persistancy too, use this code:

```
var systemPath = System.Environment.
                             GetFolderPath(
                                 Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData
                             );
var complete = Path.Combine(systemPath , "files");
```

This will generate a path like *C:\Documents and Settings\%USER NAME%\Application Data\files* folder, where you *guaranteed* to have a permission to write.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had forgotten about the privilege escalation in the new OSes. That solves my problem.

Answer (score 13):

Just use [`File.Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03.aspx):

```
File.Create("fileName");
```

This will create file inside your executable program without specifying the full path.

Don't forget to add:

```
using System.IO;
```

Comment: No, it will be created in the "current folder" which can be changed by the prog.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, You are right, but if the OP was able to change the current folder, he never asks this question.

Comment: It could happen by some lib. Even by using a FileDialog I think.

Comment: If the user has the command prompt open and is in, say, `c:\otherdir`, and runs "c:\exefile\my.exe", it will create the file in `c:\otherdir`, not `c:\exefile`.

Answer (score 8):

You can get the full path to your new file with:

```
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "\\mynewfile.txt"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string path;
   path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName( 
      System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase );
   MessageBox.Show( path );
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457089.aspx

Answer (score 2):

In modern operating systems, the accepted answer of:

```
var systemPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
    Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData
);
var complete = Path.Combine(systemPath , "files");
```

will produce a user agnostic path like: "C:\ProgramData\files"

To produce a user-based path similar to: "C:\Documents and Settings\%USER NAME%\Application Data\files"

You should use `SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` or `SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I like to give the user the choice.  I would default the directory to something like    Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData and let them read and edit the path at will. If in a console app display the path in help and allow them to pass it via command line argument.
This saves them the hassle of hunting for the folder. If they point to a path you cannot write to then you throw the error and let them decide what to do.