# Setting a path to files

Tags: c#, path

I would like to use this method https://stackoverflow.com/a/11967357/5425608 to create a file.  However, var may only be used within a method https://stackoverflow.com/a/5337470/5425608.  How do I convert the names of the paths to class variables to be accessed by other methods inside the class.

For instance, in the code below, "labelPath" is not in the scope of var labelPath of the setPaths() method.  I also have other methods that use "path" and "objectPath" and these variables are not in the scope of those methods.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        setPaths();
        current = this;
        instantiateNumUpDown();
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(labelPath, " ");

    }

    public static void setPaths()
    {
        var systemPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);

        var path = Path.Combine(systemPath, "TextDynamic.txt");
        var labelPath = Path.Combine(systemPath, "currentLabel.txt");
        var objectPath = Path.Combine(systemPath, "object.txt");

    }
```

Comment: just make `var` to `string`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this, as var is not a type itself, it gets the type of the value on the right hand side of the assignment.

Instead, you can define the variable type as string and declare under class

```
public class A
{
        private static string systemPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
        private string path = Path.Combine(systemPath, "TextDynamic.txt");
        private string labelPath = Path.Combine(systemPath, "currentLabel.txt");
        private string objectPath = Path.Combine(systemPath, "object.txt");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Form2
{
    private static string labelPath;
    private static string objectPath;
    private static string path;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        setPaths();
        current = this;
        instantiateNumUpDown();
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Form2.labelPath, " ");

    }

    public static void setPaths()
    {
        var systemPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);

        path = Path.Combine(systemPath, "TextDynamic.txt");
        labelPath = Path.Combine(systemPath, "currentLabel.txt");
        objectPath = Path.Combine(systemPath, "object.txt");

    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your variable "path" "labelPath" "objectPath" all out of From2's Construction method, to fix it, you should do like this:

```
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    string path = string.empty;
    string labelPath = string.empty;
    string objectPath = string.empty;

    setPaths(ref path, ref labelPath, ref objectPath);

    current = this;
    instantiateNumUpDown();
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(labelPath, " ");

}

public static void setPaths(ref string path, ref string labelPath, ref string objectPath)
{
    var systemPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);

    path = Path.Combine(systemPath, "TextDynamic.txt");
    labelPath = Path.Combine(systemPath, "currentLabel.txt");
    objectPath = Path.Combine(systemPath, "object.txt");

}
```